# Aggregating partial part of column meeting a condition during groupby

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, max, azure-sql-database

I have a table which has three columns as shown below:

```
ResponseId | ResponseType | ResponseDateTime

    1         Complete      2017-04-10 08:13:00.0300000 
    2         Complete      2017-03-17 05:21:00.5800000
    3         Partial       2017-02-07 16:38:14.3800000
    4         Not Started   2017-04-12 05:38:33.8366667
```

I want the table to be aggregated such that I get the total number of responses and the `LatestReponseTime` (i.e. MAX of ResponseDateTime) calculated on rows where `ReponseType = Complete`.

The resultant table look like below: -

```
NumberOfResponses  |  LatestReponseTime

     4                2017-04-10 08:13:00.0300000
```

As can be seen, the `LatestResponseTime` contains the MAX of 2017-04-10 08:13:00.0300000 and 2017-03-17 05:21:00.5800000 (The timestamp where `ResponseType = Complete`).

Can anybody help me with a T-SQL or MySQL command for achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) as NumberOfResponses,
  MAX(CASE WHEN ResponseType = 'Complete' THEN ResponseDateTime END) AS LatestReponseTime
FROM mytable;
```

Comment: What happens if the entire ResponseDateTime column is empty (NULL) or there isn't any row which has ResponseType = 'Complete' ?

Comment: Then LatestReponseTime is null. What else could we expect?

Answer (score 1):

Use the case

```
    select count(ResponseId), max(case when ResponseType='Complete' then 
ResponseDateTime end) from TableName;
```